# PDF file download interrupted when on wifi network

Tags: pdf, networking, joomla, wifi, dompdf

I have a really strange problem. When I'm on wifi, I cannot normally download PDF file (works only every fourth of fifth time) which is generated in Joomla by DomPdf. I get the error in Firefox "...pdf.part could not be saved, because the source file could not be read". It doesn't work also with other browsers. We have several Wifi routers on house, and it does not work with any of them.

When connected to same network with cable, everything works as it should. Is there some general wifi router settings that interferes with this?

Any other networking (downloading PDF-s from other sites etc.) is working ok with wifi.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Might be a security setting that blocks PDF files or downloads in general.

Comment: I can download other pdf-s from same site with no problem also with wifi. It seems that only this dompdf generated file has problems on wifi :(

Comment: In which case there is either a problem with the PDF itself, the naming convention might need to be changed, else you should contact the developer of DomPDF ;)

Comment: Thanks, i would have thought so also, but with cable it works absolutely fine. So there should probably be some general wifi router setting that is interfering.

Comment: Any luck with this one? Really makes me curious. I wonder if it's the fact that the PDF size isn't reported. Or maybe the chunking is bad? Or maybe the packet size is too big. What happens if you save the PDF to the server then redirect to that file (if you can do that)?

Comment: this is solution for that issue https://stackoverflow.com/a/66524127/8450603

Answer (score 0):

If you are still having this problem Disable GZip compression in your Global Config, and the Download will be fine

Comment: Thanks, but i checked and GZIP compresion was already set to "no" in Joomla global configuration :(